# Is there anything like webrick for ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webserver

This might seem a really bizarre question, but just go with me for a second.

When you install rails, you have to opportunity to test your development on webrick, a very simple web server (or you can use mongrel if you have the gem installed).

I know when developing ASP.NET you can use the built-in server that comes with Visual Studio, but I wondered if there was something you could have if you didn't have a copy of visual studio or didn't know how to configure IIS but still wanted to run an ASP.NET web application, say on your home PC or laptop.

As I said, a bizarre question, but I just thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) which is a lightweight free version of IIS.